# How to use ffmpeg to cut audio into overlapping segments?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg

I have used the following code in python to cut an audio file to equal parts with a length of 5 seconds:

```
import subprocess
command = "ffmpeg -i audio.wav -f segment -segment_time 5-c copy every_5_sec/out%03d.wav"
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

But I need overlapping parts. In other words, I need an audio segment to contain one second of the previous and one second of the next audio segments.

Comment: Not possible with the segment muxer as far as I know. You'll have to use `-ss` and `-t` / `-to` or atrim and asetpts filters.

Comment: ffmpeg's process architecture makes this unwieldy to support. Since you're segmenting PCM audio, simlpy run the command in a loop with the ss times adjusted and -t as 7 except for the first segment.